# Java - Imprimir na porta Bematech_COM3

Tags: java

Preciso imprimir um papel não fiscal em Java.

Na máquina do cliente já existe uma Bematech 4200 instalada na porta Bematech_COM3:

Estou tentando imprimir usando o seguinte método:

```
private void imprimir(String frase) {
    //Gera o arquivo de desconto
    try {
        File arquivo = new File("teste.txt");
        if (arquivo.exists()) {
            //se existir
            FileWriter arquivoTxt = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
            PrintWriter linhasTxt = new PrintWriter(arquivoTxt);
            //ACREDITO QUE SO PODE TER 42 CARACTERES
            linhasTxt.println("==========================================");
            linhasTxt.println("            Thiosti Restaurante           ");
            linhasTxt.println("===========================================");
            linhasTxt.println("********** NAO E DOCUMENTO FISCAL *********");
            linhasTxt.println("===========================================");
            linhasTxt.println("============= CUPOM DE DESCONTO ============");
            linhasTxt.println("===========================================");
            linhasTxt.println(frase);
            linhasTxt.println("===========================================");
            linhasTxt.println("       Agradecemos a preferencia!        ");
            linhasTxt.println("Delivery - 3095-3838");
            //emiteComanda();
        } else {
            //se não existir
            arquivo.createNewFile();
            //criaTxt();
        }
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("nao encontrei arquivo");
    }

    try {
        java.io.InputStream is = new FileInputStream("teste.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Bematech_COM3:");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fs);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String linhas = sc.nextLine();
            ps.println(linhas);
        }
        fs.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro encontrado ao imprimir comanda." + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma mais simples de se imprimir diretamente nesta porta? Pois está sempre caindo no catch.

Obrigado.

Comment: Pode adicionar a mensagem de erro aue esta aparecendo?